# Looking to speed up my php mysqli query inside loop based on date

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 tables.
`cif_schedules`, `cif_locations`, and `TRUST_activation`, and `TRUST_MOVEMENT`

CIF schedules table, has a list of bus services and their IDs along with various not so relevant bits of information.

This CIF schedules table is inner joined on to the cif_locations table by means of matching ID field. Through this joined statement, the query is based on the TIPLOC field on cif_locations, something like this.

```
SELECT cif_schedules.id FROM cif_schedules 
   INNER JOIN cif_locations ON cif_schedules.id = cif_locations.id
WHERE cif_locations.tiploc = "BUSTERM" order by sort_time ASC
```

So the query, selects a list of IDs of bus services `WHERE tiploc (abb of Timing Point Location)` matches the users input (in this case `BUS TERM[inal]`)

Thereafter, inside a PHP while loop, cycling through each of the IDs ordering by sort_time. Inside said while loop, the following happens

I search through a table called TRUST , also where the CIF Id field is present. This is a basic query

Then if a TRUST row is found, assign variable "activated", and then lookup the current movement data for that TRUST row

So for each CIF schedule (around 600, from a table of around 200,000), look up trust ID (only 1 needed), then if that is found, lookup latest movement (around 20, need most recent, from a table of a few hundred thousand

===EDIT===please find below my code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT created, trust_id, deduced FROM trust_activation WHERE cif_schedule_id = ? AND substring(trust_id FROM 9) = ? AND created > ? AND created < ? ORDER BY deduced")
$stmt->bind_param('siss', $schedid, $qdom, $lastmonth, $nextmonth);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($t_created, $trust_id, $deduced);
if($stmt->fetch()){
    assign variable $status the value "activated".
}
$stmt->close();
```

Then- If variable `status` has value "activated, then run the following code.

```
 if($status == "activated"){
         $actual = "";
         $mins = "";
         $difference = "";
         $hrs = "";
         $scheduled = "";
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT created, platform, loc_stanox, actual_timestamp, planned_timestamp, timetable_variation FROM trust_movement WHERE trust_id = ? AND created > ? AND created < ? ORDER BY actual_timestamp DESC, planned_timestamp DESC, created DESC LIMIT 1");
         $stmt->bind_param('sss', $trust_id, $lastmonth, $nextmonth);
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->store_result();
         $stmt->bind_result($m_created, $m_plat, $m_loc_stanox, $m_actual, $m_planned, $m_ttvar);
         if($stmt->fetch()){
                 $clocation = $m_loc_stanox;
                 $status = "running";
                 date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
                 $actual = $m_actual;
                 $scheduled = $m_planned;
                 if($actual >= $scheduled){
                         $mins           =       date("i", substr($actual - $scheduled, 0, 10));
                         $hrs            =       date("H", substr($actual - $scheduled, 0, 10));
                         $difference     =       ($mins + ($hrs * 60)) . " Late!";
                 }else{
                         $mins           =       date("i", substr($scheduled - $actual, 0, 10));
                         $hrs            =       date("H", substr($scheduled - $actual, 0, 10));
                         $difference     =       ($mins + ($hrs * 60)) . " Early!";
                 }
         }else{
         }
         $stmt->close();
 }
```

Now all of this code is inside a WHILE loop, running for each CIF schedule found. Finding the CIF schedules on their own is already pretty fast as its not very big table.

The tables have the following INDEXES

TRUST activation

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   cif_schedule_id BTREE   No  No  cif_schedule_id 96062   A   No  
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   trust_id    BTREE   No  No  trust_id    227540  A   No  
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   created BTREE   No  No  created 41938   A   No
```

TRUST_MOVEMENT

```
Action  Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   trust_id    BTREE   No  No  trust_id    264975  A   No  
Edit Edit   Drop Drop   created BTREE   No  No  created 164019  A   No
```

For around 600 cif rows with their associated TRUST data, the page takes around 10 seconds to load. Is there any way I can potentially half this?

Comment: Do you have indexes on all fields used in search criteria and joins? and are you using prepared statements ?

Comment: I believe I'm using some form of indexing but it will be worth me checking in the morning. I am not using prepared statements for my intensive search queries like those in my question - should I be using prepared statements? During the above, I've already sanitised and used a prepared statement to get the users search term. These nested looped style queries I'm not using prepared statements I assumed they wouldnt make any difference if there's no risk of an injection attack.

Comment: That can potentially speed up your queries a lot. Using prepared statements will help speed up queries if they are repeatedly used in  a loop. Let me know if i should post it as an answer :)

Comment: I'm about to go to bed but will check in the morning and come back :-) thanks and will confirm tomorrow

Comment: Hi, ive added the prepared statements as shown above but it doesn't make any difference to the performance. Have I done them correctly?

Comment: Cant set any finger on it, but have a few suggestions. First of all string manipulation like "substring(trust_id FROM 9)"  will always slow it down at some degree. Second i think that adding indexes to your order by cols could make a difference to

Comment: is it out of the question to do it all in one query by joining the two tables ?

Comment: I'd assume so, as I need to return cif schedule results regardless of whether they are: activated or not; or left their original location or not. If I were to join them all up into one, wouldn't that mean that they'd return no rows if they havent been activated or left their origin, despite the cif timetable record being found?

Comment: Not if you are using a "LEFT JOIN". then the activation data would just come back as NULL's if they dont exist.

Comment: If none of this is helping then i am a bit out of ideas of how to speed your queries up. Then you might be into some optimization of your database setup or throwing some faster hardware after it.... but that is out of my league :-)

Comment: Thanks, Ill look into using a left join.

Comment: Just inner joined a few tables, seems noticably quciker - only by about 1 or 2 seconds however. Im being a bit cheap with my VPS, itll probably need upgrading. Its 1VCPU, 1GB RAM with 1GB swap. I set the innodb buffer to 3GB as per mysqltuner's recommendations.